# PHP non greedy regex

Tags: php, html, regex

I wrote a regex to find out href from anchor tag
My regex is

```
<a.*?href="(.*?)">blah<\/a> //dot is matching all
```

So according to me, this will start matching from `<a` until it finds out first `href`. After this it will grab the url in href until first `"` and then it will match for blah.
But this is matching multiple sets of anchor tags which have blah tag in end, for example:

```
<a href="some_url">abc</a>
<a href="some_url1">def</a>
<a href="get_this">blah</a>
```

According to me it should grab only last url as regex fits it perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by "perfectly"? You regexp matches the whole code because of the `.*?` part.

Comment: well that "perfectly" part is according to me and I'm definitely wrong. And isn't .*? should stop before it matches next character as it is non-greedy match?

Comment: It'll match the whole tag but the `href` is in first captured group `$1`

Comment: Your regex works fine for me. Try putting your regex in here at: http://regex101.com/ . Put those three <a> tags in and you will see that it only matches the last line and captures "get_this".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question, you can swap your dot operator for a not group, to match everything but the closing tag:

```regex
<a[^>]*href="([^"]*)">def<\/a>
```

This (in theory) ensures that the regex pattern will only match inside a particular tag.

To not answer your question: it's often not a great idea to parse HTML with regex, unless you can be extremely sure of exactly how it's formatted. You might want to look into the [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).